# MySQL: ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied - Cannot CREATE USER

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.5.16 noinstall Zip Archive on Win7.

After I started the server, the command `show databases` showed me a list of 2 databases: `information_schema` and `test`. The latter is empty.

Where is the table `user`?

I tried to create a new user through this command `create user newUser;` and got the following error message: `ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation`

What should I do to create, databases, tables, and do all the operations I want to do? I don't know if the fact that I'm using `MySQL 5.5.16 noinstall Zip Archive` has something to do with the error message?

Answer (score 97):

First thing to do is run this:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

You will quickly see you were assigned the anonymous user to authenticate into mysql.

Instead of logging into mysql with

```
mysql
```

login like this:

```
mysql -uroot
```

By default, root@localhost has all rights and no password.

If you cannot login as root without a password, do the following:

Step 01) Add the two options in the mysqld section of my.ini:

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
skip-networking
```

Step 02) Restart mysql

```
net stop mysql
<wait 10 seconds>
net start mysql
```

Step 03) Connect to mysql

```
mysql
```

Step 04) Create a password from root@localhost

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=password('whateverpasswordyoulike')
WHERE user='root' AND host='localhost';
exit
```

Step 05) Restart mysql

```
net stop mysql
<wait 10 seconds>
net start mysql
```

Step 06) Login as root with password

```
mysql -u root -p
```

You should be good from there.

CAVEAT: [Please remove anonymous users !!!](https://serverfault.com/questions/316552/weird-mysql-users-been-created-eg-bug115166-10073-and-not-by-me/316554#316554)

Comment: @CharlieParker `my.ini` is the Configuration File for MySQL/Windows. I mentioned `my.ini` since the Question starts with `I'm using MySQL 5.5.16 noinstall Zip Archive on Win7.`

Comment: You can add __Step 01)__ lines in __/usr/local/mysql/my.cnf__ file in __Mac OS X__

Comment: This has worked for me. However, as a side effect, it made my java application fail to connect to a database with a database specific user (i.e. not root). Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: Alternative to @goker.cebeci suggestion: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: Another alternative to @goker.cebeci suggestion (homebrew + mariadb) : `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: For some reason, installation of mariadb 10.4, by default added `emptystring@'localhost'` user. Now, I'm looking to add the file into .cnf file.. where shall I place that in CentOS 7 system?

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was ( for a very strange reason ) the fact that root had `Host` of `%` instead of `localhost`

I received the above error when trying to `DROP USER`;
Privileges as suggested in the answer above - I already had, so the solution wasn't suitable for me.

The DB looked like this:

```
mysql> drop user 'testuser'@'%';
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SYSTEM_USER privilege(s) for this operation

mysql> select Host,User,drop_priv from user;
+------+------------------+-----------+
| Host | User             | drop_priv |
+------+------------------+-----------+
| %    | mysql.infoschema | N         |
| %    | mysql.session    | N         |
| %    | mysql.sys        | N         |
| %    | root             | Y         |
+------+------------------+-----------+
```

And

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'%';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO `root`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried many things, but eventually I changed the `Host` from `%` to `localhost` for security concerns, nothing else.

```
mysql> UPDATE user SET Host='localhost' WHERE user='root' LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

I don't know why, but it worked.

```
mysql> quit

$ mysql -u root -p
.. ENTER (NO PASSWORD) ..

mysql> drop user 'testuser'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

No idea why, but hope it will help others ...
I'm using CentOS which has SELinux and other stuff, which maybe other components are correlated with this. don't know.

Comment: also i have same issue , in root user cant delete other users