# system error 1060 has occurred in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am following the below post here [MySQL: ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied - Cannot CREATE USER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797543/mysql-error-1227-42000-access-denied-cannot-create-user.Following) the posts here I am getting the when I run the command net stop MySQL I am getting the following error

> System Error 1060: The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

Can someone tell me what should I do to get this rid of this error.

Comment: it might be because the user or authentication cannot modify the database users

Comment: Would a solution -> http://support.citrix.com/article/ctx108387 , http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,11388,11388