# MySQL: ERROR 1227 (42000) on school server

Tags: mysql, linux, unix

Hi I want to create a user but its failing because I don’t have privilleges?  I was logged in with “mysql –u huraibz001 –p” 
This was the folowing error message that I had received:

> ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

I also couldn’t create a database, surely this also has to do something with my privilleges.
Then I had tried “show grants;” and it has shown me this:

```
Grants for huraibz001@localhost
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'huraibz001'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'blablabla'
```

I also could do the folowing  ” select user(), current_user();” which gave me:

```
+----------------------+----------------------+
| user()               | current_user()       |
+----------------------+----------------------+
| huraibz001@localhost | huraibz001@localhost |
+----------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I also have tried to login in with “mysql -uroot -p” but that doesn’t work, because I think huraibz001 is the root.  Could someone please tell me the solution in steps?

Comment: If you are not in possession of the system root account or other privileged account, you cannot create a user unless someone grants it to you.  You will need to talk to whomever is the administrator of that database server to get `GRANT` permissions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is run this:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

You will quickly see you were assigned the anonymous user to authenticate into mysql.

Instead of logging into mysql with

```
mysql
```

login like this:

```
mysql -uroot
```

By default, root@localhost has all rights and no password.

If you cannot login as root without a password, do the following:

Step 01) Add the two options in the mysqld section of my.ini:

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
skip-networking
```

Step 02) Restart mysql

```
net stop mysql
<wait 10 seconds>
net start mysql
```

Step 03) Connect to mysql

```
mysql
```

Step 04) Create a password from root@localhost

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=password('whateverpasswordyoulike')
WHERE user='root' AND host='localhost';
exit
```

Step 05) Restart mysql

```
net stop mysql
<wait 10 seconds>
net start mysql
```

Step 06) Login as root with password

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

You should be good from there.

CAVEAT: [Please remove anonymous users !!!](https://serverfault.com/questions/316552/weird-mysql-users-been-created-eg-bug115166-10073-and-not-by-me/316554#316554)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7797689/2118383)