# Writing 'mysql -u root -p' and hitting ENTER in cmd just starts a new row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to login to my MySQL database through Windows 7 command line. After I run `mysql`, I get confirmation that MySQL is set up on my PC.

However, when I write `-u root -p` or `mysql -u root -p` and hit `ENTER`, the cmd just starts on a new line without executing my code. So it looks like this:

```
mysql> -u root -p [HIT ENTER here]
       ->_ [blinking low dash]
```

Note that my code is executed if I write `SHOW DATABASES` etc.

Why is `cmd` not executing my code?

Comment: Because you didn't terminate your query with a semicolon? The shell expects you end your query when you’re done, no matter how many lines this may take. And you don’t need the `-u root -p` part obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why exactly my code was not running, but I managed to solve the problem.

Basically, the suggestions offered by `@leuanG` were correct. However, the issue was that from the beginning I was assigned the anonymous user `'.'@'localhost'`, instead of `'root'@'localhost'`.

To fix this, reopen `cmd` and, instead of running `mysql` to log in to MySQL, run `mysql -uroot -p`. Then you will be asked for the password you have in your `config` file. Enter it, hit `ENTER` and it's good to go.

Half of the solution came from the answer here: [MySQL: ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied - Cannot CREATE USER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797543/mysql-error-1227-42000-access-denied-cannot-create-user/7797689)

Answer (score -1):

By the looks of it, you don't have a password set for root. It's just taking you through to the prompt. To set a password, you can use for versions 5.7.6 and later:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

or this for versions 5.7.5 and earlier:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

You can find your MySQL version by running `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: I wrote in my question that I've tried this option as well. Still the same.

Comment: This is weird, I get 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mariadb server version for the right syntax to use near mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';'. Any suggestions?

Comment: @IsaaK08 Can you run `SELECT VERSION();` for me? The syntax is different for older versions. I've updated the answer for older versions.

Comment: It's the 10.1.26-MariaDB version

Comment: Did you by any chance type in the mysql> bit? Type in everything after that prompt, so `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';`

Comment: The main issue was that from the start I was assigned an anonymous user (`'.'@'localhost'`). So I had to login using `mysql -uroot -p` instead of just `mysql` and it's somewhat fixed. However, the syntax above still throws errors.