# mysql user creation error 42000

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a new user with all privileges, so I tried this code in mysql:

```
create user 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

and I got this error

> ### -------------- create user 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
>
> ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the
>   CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

Note :I already read this question and the answers (and tried them):

1. [MySQL: ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied - Cannot CREATE USER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797543/mysql-error-1227-42000-access-denied-cannot-create-user)

Comment: You probably need to be root to do that. Do SELECT USER(); to see who you're logged in as, then check the privileges you have with that user.

Comment: What is the question? Did you want to know what that error means, or why that error is being returned? Did you want to know if this is expected behavior? Is this a bug in MySQL? Is this documented in the MySQL Reference Manual? Did you want to know how to create a user? (Currently this reads more like a status report than a question.)

Comment: how to create n new user with all privileges

Comment: @flip im login as root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what user you are logged in as:

```
SELECT USER();
```

To see the privileges of the user you are logged in as:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

To identify users that have "CREATE USER" privilege:

```
SELECT u.user, u.host, u.create_user_priv FROM mysql.user u ORDER BY u.user, u.host ;
```

If DML changes are made to the `mysql.user`, `mysql.db` et al. tables, then we can issue this statement to have MySQL re-read the tables to make those changes effective:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;
```

---

To a get a `CREATE USER` statement executed, we need to be logged in as a user that has the `CREATE USER` privilege.

Or (less desirable) logged in as a user that has sufficient privileges, we can manually issue a DML `INSERT` statement to add a new row to `mysql.user` table, and then run the `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` statement.

Or (as a last resort), if we don't have login credentials for any suitable user, we can get MySQL restarted with the `--skip-grant-tables` option, and then make changes to the `mysql.user` table (using DML INSERT and/or UPDATE statements), and then restart MySQL again (this time without the `--skip-grant-tables` option.)